# Jawbone: Registered Webhook not being called

Tags: publish-subscribe, webhooks, jawbone

I've just started looking at the Jawbone API so please forgive any rookie mistakes.

I've successfully navigated OAuth and I'm now able to pull data from endpoints. I've registered a webhook for my server at `https://example.com/webhook.php` and I got a success message

```
{"meta": 
    {"user_xid": "<redacted>", 
    "message": "Registered webhook for user", 
    "code": 200, 
    "time": 1469983151}, 
    "data": {}
}
```

However, I can't see the webhook being called at all. None of the code within the script seems to be running, so I've looked in the webserver logs and there are no requests happening in there.

I've tried adding and deleting moods in the app to get something to happen, and tried syncing the jawbone itself and nothing seems to get the webhook to fire.

My API application isn't published (yet), I hope that's not a barrier here, because I want to test thoroughly first. Is there another step I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but just in case: did you enable Pub Sub for your app in the web portal? Did you add a global webhook?

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question. Yeah, I tried the global webhook first, so enabled and put in my URL. After that didn't seem to be working, I tried manually registering the hook via the API. I didn't disable the global when I tried manually registering.

Comment: Could you email your app id to apisupport@jawbone.com? I'm gonna need to look at the specifics of your setup to see what's going on.

Comment: @RAY Thanks, I have just emailed.

Comment: @RAY I haven't heard anything back?

Comment: Just replied to your email. I need some details about your testing. Thanks.